# Microsoft Office 2010 Starter stop working

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2010, microsoft-office-starter

Recently my Office Starter 2010 stopped working and asked to be repaired, I do so but still is not working.

Is there some way to uninstall and install Office Starter 2010?
I searched on Google but nothing more precise about this issue.
I know that is not a license problem because it says that Office Starter does not expire.

So I wonder what could be causing this error?

Comment: Have you tried going into the control panel, finding it, and then repairing from there?

Comment: If you have the media and license keys at hand I'd recommend uninstalling Office, running a reg cleaner such as http://www.ccleaner.com and then reinstalling Office.

Comment: @MoifMurphy Office starter only has a "CD key" if you're an OEM and buy at least 1000 licenses at a time

Comment: Can you further explain how 'it's not working'?  What happens when you try to run it?  If there are error messages, what are they?  Is anything reported in the Windows Event Logs? Have you performed disk checks (chkdsk), and/or system file checks (sfc /scannow)?

Comment: I uninstall with Revo Uninstaller and CCleaner, how install it again now ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just uninstall it and reinstall it.

If you're in *Windows 7* then go to **Control Panel** then **Programs and Features**.

If you're in *Windows XP* then go to **Control Panel** then **Add/Remove Programs**.

Then look for *Microsoft Office 2010* and click <kbd>Uninstall</kbd>.

**To re-install:**

[Microsoft Office 2010 Starter Edition](http://forums.mydigitallife.info/threads/21441-Office-2010-Starter)

Follow the guide at that link above.

Comment: but how re-install office starter ?

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I fixed the problem:

1. go to Control Panel, then Programs and Features
2. select "Uninstall or change a program"
3. select Microsoft Word Starter 2010, and select the Change option
4. select OK when the dialogue box appears

Make sure you connected to the internet in order to complete the process.